# Proper Settings for SQL Server 2005 Profiler User Auditing

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql, sql-server

I have been tasked with creating a catalog of all users\applications that access a particular database at our company.  The issue is that we have no idea what users are using the database and what they are doing (what queries they are using or stored procedures).   I would like to run this over a few days, but want to minimize the amount of information that is returned in the trace, could anyone please advise me on what the minimal settings for Profiler are for this.

Answer (score 1):

Start by recording the "Security Audit   Audit Login" event.  At a minimum you want the LoginName, Hostname, DatabaseID and StartTime columns to be recorded.